# Implement iterator of a circular list

Tags: c++, list, iterator

I'm trying to implement a class of Circular List with a nested class of iterator and I wrote like this:

```
template <class T>
class CircularList {
    struct Item {
        T data;
        Item* next;
    };
    Item* head;
    int size;
public:
    CircularList() {
        head = new Item();
        head->next = head;
    }
    int sizeList() { return size; }
    void push(T data) {
        Item* i = new Item();
        i->data = data;
        i->next = head->next;
        head->next = i;
        size++;
    }
    class CircularListIterator {
        Item* p;
        CircularListIterator() {
            p = head->next;
        }
        bool hasNext() {
            if(p->next != head) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        T next() {
            T data_temp = p->data;
            p = p->next;
            return data_temp;
        }
};
            CircularListIterator* iterator() {
                return new CircularListIterator();
            }
    }; 

int main() {
    CircularList<string>* letters = new CircularList<string>;
    letters->push("d");
    letters->push("c");
    letters->push("b");
    letters->push("a");

    Iterator<string>* it= new Iterator<string>;
    it = letters->iterator();
    while (it->hasNext()) {
        cout<< it->next() << "," << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But the Iterator is not working when I try to create an iterator in the main function, It said that it wasn't declared in the scope and has no member of it.

Comment: You don't need all those `new`.

Comment: please post the exact error message

Comment: `CircularListIterator` should be constructed with the appropriate values for `p`. One for `begin()` and one for `end()`. The `CircularListIterator` instance does not know which `CircularList<T>` instance it "belongs to" so to speak.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming by "in the main class" you mean in the `main` *function*, the problem is quite straightforward: you're trying to construct a `::Iterator<string>`, but there is no class in the global namespace (or anywhere else, in this code sample) called `Iterator`! You could try constructing a `CircularList<string>::CircularListIterator` - that's at least a class that exists - but it wouldn't work because the iterator needs to be associated with a `CircularList` object for it to be able to access member variables like `head`.

The correct thing to do here is to promote the `iterator` function - the one that returns a `CircularListIterator*` - out of the `CircularListIterator` class and into the `CircularList` class. Then, in your `main` function, you can call `letters->iterator()` and it'll return a `CircularListIterator*` for the `letters` object.

Now, `CircularListIterator` doesn't inherit from any other iterator classes - neither the (nonexistent-in-this-code `Iterator` you've typed `it` as, nor the C++ `std::iterator` or any of its variants) - so you can't assign it to `it` or probably even compile the code that references `Iterator`. To make `CircularListIterator` a subclass of `std::iterator`, you'll need to extend `std::iterator<Category, T>` with the appropriate category. See https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/iterator/ for more information on the `std::iterator` class template, including an example of implementing it.

Comment: It will return iterator initialized with a null pointer...

Comment: Maybe you mean `letters->iterator();`, I did this but I still have error in the `Iterator<string>* it= new Iterator<string>;`, maybe do you know how should I write this?

Comment: @Xavi Minimal correction: https://godbolt.org/z/8fYWhKWMY

Comment: Ah, since `letters` is a pointer, yes, use `->` (edited). You're getting a type error assigning to `it`, because `CircularListIterator<string>` is not an `Iterator<string>`, neither directly nor by inheritance. As mentioned in the answer, that class doesn't even exist in the code as given. Editing in something about `std::iterator` though.